# How To Delete a Replaced File in AntD Upload on maxCount set to 1?

Tags: reactjs, antd

So i want my antd is just uploading one file so i set the maxCount to 1. I have set actions property the upload api endpoint and call the delete api endpoint on onRemove property. It should work properly.

just one problem. When file is being forced to be replaced it
did not call the delete api endpoint at onRemove property. So if user change did not click the remove button, the file is still there on the server.

i try to upload single file in antd upload component

```
<Form.Item
           label="FILE"
           name={["file"]}
           valuePropName="file"
           getValueFromEvent={getValueFromEvent}
           rules={[{ required: true }]}
        >
           <Upload.Dragger
              name="file"
              multiple={false}
              maxCount={1}
              action={${backend}/file}
           >
              <p className="ant-upload-text">ADD A FILE </p>
           </Upload.Dragger>
        </Form.Item>
```